# Security issues from uploading files to the system

Tags: php, security, file-upload

I understand that security issues usually come from user inputs which is why I am assuming there is a security hole in the else part of $eFlag!=1.
I am not familiar with php so I am not 100% sure what is going on here.

I am assuming that file itself that is being uploaded could be some malicious executable and that is not being checked???
If so, is there ways to prevent uploading executable or just upload .doc files (looks like that's the file that the program wants)?

***This was posted on one of the clubs that I am in for school and asked to identify a security hole (in another words, there is one for sure).

[image]

Comment: Regardless of what was uploaded, the script will tack on a .doc extension.  Not sure whether that qualifies as security risk or just plain stupidity.

Comment: exactly.. so how do I make sure that it's a doc file? so then, if it is in fact, a .doc file then I will upload instead of just uploading whatever and putting a .doc extension on it.

Comment: A relatively safe way is to check the file's [signature](http://www.garykessler.net/library/file_sigs.html) although .doc files are well known for their vulnerability to embedded malicious elements.  If that's an option I'd say first determine the file type as well as you can (and use an appropriate file extension on the saved file), and second pass it through a virussscanner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check mime types of uploaded file:

```
strcmp(substr(mime_content_type($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']),0,4),"doc"
```

Full example on php.net for checking mime types: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mime-content-type.php

Full code with added filter of filename name and length (this is based on filename):

```
$match = preg_match_all("/^[a-zA-Z0-9]/$", $_FILES['userfile']['name'], $matchif);

if (!$matchif)
{
    die('not allowed filename');
}

if (strlen($_FILES['userfile']['name']) > 255 || strlen($_FILES['userfile']['name'] == 0))
{
    die('Filename length not allowed');
}

if (strcmp(substr(mime_content_type($_FILES['userfile']['name']),0,4),"doc")==0) 
{ 

    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']))
    {
        // upload file
    }
    else die('not upload');

}
else die('support only doc');
```

You can dump and use conditionals to check mimetypes as examples:

```
var_dump($_FILES['userfile']['type']);

if ($_FILES['userfile']['type'] == 'application/msword') { ... move uploaded files ...  }
```

Notice: mime types can be faked, so i will check via filename, types via $_FILES, length of filename, and read first lines of code to check if DOC or something else. Open it doc in notepad and see what you can check in PHP by reading file.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, there a two ways an uploaded file can be invoked: either directly or indirectly.

The direct way would be to call it by its URL. In that case, it’s the file name extension that gives the web server the hint what to do with it. So you need to make sure, that the file is not stored with a file name extension that is executable (i.e. not `.php`) or that the files are stored at a location that cannot be reached via HTTP.

The indirect way would be to have another invoked file include the uploaded file using `include`, etc. So you need make sure that if the arguments for `include`, etc. are parameterized, the parameter cannot be manipulated by user inputs, otherwise you’re vulnerable to [remote/local file inclusion](http://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/98.html).